# jquery circle progress showing incorrect percentage

Tags: jquery, html, css-shapes

I have been using following jquery circle-progress, recently i have noticed an issue with value 0.29. It should show 29% but instead 28% is being displayed.

https://github.com/kottenator/

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.progressbar').each(function () {
    var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    var percent = $('input[id$=hdProfitPerc]').val();  //$(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
    var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
    var animate = $(this).data('animate');
    var Profit = $('input[id$=hdProfit]').val();
    //alert($('input[id$=hdProfitPerc]').val());

    var clr

    if (percent < 0) {
        clr = 'red'
    }
    else {
        clr = 'green'
    }

    if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() - 30 && !animate) {
        $(this).data('animate', true);
        $(this).find('.small-circle').circleProgress({
            startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
            value: 0.29, //percentage,
            thickness: 8,
            fill: {
                color: clr
            }
        }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress, stepValue) {
            //$(this).find('div').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2) + '%');
            $(this).find('div').text(parseInt(stepValue * 100) + '%');
        }).stop()
         .on('circle-animation-end', function (event) {
             $(this).find('#GP').html(Profit);
         })
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress/1.2.0/dist/circle-progress.js"></script>
<div id="div_progressbar" runat="server">
  <div class="progressbar" style="padding-left: 80px;">
    <div class="small-circle">
      <div></div>
      <span id="GP" style="color: black"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If i change value from 0.29 to 0.291 then it works.

Comment: this does work $(this).find('div').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(2) + '%'); but won't work for 100% instead shows 00%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fix:

```
   $(this).find('div').text(Math.round(parseFloat(stepValue * 100)) + '%');
```

Or, just:  `$(this).find('div').text(Math.round(stepValue * 100) + '%');`

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/tq4jok5r/2/

After tests, i've noticed that this particular number (28,999999xxxx) is rounded to smaller integer ... P.S. Works fine with more different values, tested few...

Comment: @user1263981, well...Math.round should work, then :) Check edit, please.

Comment: this works fine :) , i think there is no need for parseFloat

Comment: @user1263981, try 0.29 and parseInt() -> again 28 is returned. So, rather use parseFloat(). :)

Comment: no this returns 29      $(this).find('div').text(Math.round(stepValue * 100) + '%'); Math.round is enough i believe

Comment: @user1263981, great, even better - so Math.round was solution, anyway... :)